# How to get rangeSelector to work with HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to use HighStocks rangeSelector with HighCharts? If not, is there another method someone could suggest?  Seems like this useful function would be available to both libraries.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use highstock.js and initialize highcharts with `rangeSelector` like in the example:

http://jsfiddle.net/73DyX/

Comment: thanks so much for the help. Getting acquainted highcharts and PHP has been a struggle. This will save me a ton of time

Answer (score 4):

range selector is a feature used with highstock. if you want a similar implementation with highchart you can get something like [this](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail)

It is a dynamic master-detail chart which may be of use for you.

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge the range selector is not something that you can use with HighCharts.  You have to use HighStock to get that functionality.

Highstock handles time-based data, which is why the range selector is available to you. HighCharts doesn't handle time data all that well (it can be done, but it's less flexible).  Since most of the functionality of HighCharts is found in HighStock you're probably better off to just use HighStock for whatever application needs the range selector.